# NameError: name 'ds' is not defined

Tags: large-language-model, openaiembeddings

class Embed:
def **init**(self):
self.transformer = SentenceTransformer(model_name, device="cuda")

```
def __call__(self, text_batch: List[str]): embeddings = self.transformer.encode(
        text_batch,
        batch_size=100, 
        device="cuda",
    ).tolist()

    return list(zip(text_batch, embeddings))
```

ds = ds.map_batches(
Embed,
batch_size=100,
compute=ray.data.ActorPoolStrategy(min_size=20, max_size=20),
num_gpus=1,
)

ds is defined and I am still getting this error. Can someone please help me with this?